# How to join multiple table from mysql database and display using view list in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, join

Hye! I want to know how to display data from multiple table in mysql database and display the data using view list in android...

Unfortunatey I'm getting this error for my php :

Warning: mysqli_query(): (23000/1052): Column 'empUsername' in where clause is ambiguous in C:\xampp\htdocs\elba\TRYreportclockIN.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\elba\TRYreportclockIN.php on line 14
{"result":[]}

The situation is I have two table :

-attendancedetail

-attendancedetailclockout

From table attendancedetail I want all data from this table such as :

-atdId

-atdClockIn

-empId

-empUsername

From table attendancedetailclockout I only want data :

-atdClockOut

Here is my TRYreportclockIN.php :

```
<?php 

    $empUsername= $_GET['empUsername'];

require_once('connectDB.php');

    $con = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

$sql = "SELECT i.*, o.atdClockOut FROM attendancedetail i join attendancedetailclockout o on i.empUsername=o.empUsername WHERE empUsername='$empUsername' ";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
        array_push($result,array
        ('atdId'=>$row[0],
        'atdClockIn'=>$row[1],
        'empId'=>$row[2],
        'empUsername'=>$row[3],
        'atdClockOut'=>$row[1]));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

activity_tryreportclock_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
tools:context=".TRYreportclockIn">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/atdId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/atdClockIn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/atdClockOut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

TRYreportclockIn.java

```
package com.atiemt.elba_employee;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class TRYreportclockIn extends AppCompatActivity {

String myJSON;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ATDID = "atdId";
private static final String TAG_ATDCLOCKIN ="atdClockIn";
private static final String TAG_ATDCLOCKOUT = "atdClockOut";
private static final String TAG_EMPID ="empId";
private static final String TAG_EMPUSERNAME ="empUsername";

JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tryreportclock_in);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    getData();
}


protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String atdId = c.getString(TAG_ATDID);
            String atdClockIn = c.getString(TAG_ATDCLOCKIN);
            String atdClockOut = c.getString(TAG_ATDCLOCKOUT);
            String empId = c.getString(TAG_EMPID);
            String empUsername = c.getString(TAG_EMPUSERNAME);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ATDID,atdId);
            persons.put(TAG_ATDCLOCKIN,atdClockIn);
            persons.put(TAG_ATDCLOCKOUT,atdClockOut);
            persons.put(TAG_EMPID,empId);
            persons.put(TAG_EMPUSERNAME,empUsername);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                TRYreportclockIn.this, personList, R.layout.activity_list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ATDID,TAG_ATDCLOCKIN,TAG_ATDCLOCKOUT,TAG_EMPID,TAG_EMPUSERNAME},
                new int[]{R.id.atdId, R.id.atdClockIn, R.id.atdClockOut, R.id.empId, R.id.empUsername}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.22/elba/TRYreportclockIN.php?empUsername=");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}


}
```

I'm not so sure about my coding in android studio and php...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that there are two columns with the same name in different tables and as you use a joint query, MySQL does not know which column to use.

You have to use the dot notation in the where clause just like in the join

```
SELECT i.*, o.atdClockOut FROM attendancedetail i join attendancedetailclockout o on i.empUsername=o.empUsername WHERE o.empUsername='$empUsername'
```

---

**NOTE :** Your code is vulnerable against SQL injections : You **have to** verify the user input before using it in the query AND you should use prepared statements. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)